# get cookie browser from servlet

Tags: java, maven, servlets, cookies

I using **Maven web application** for my web service.
I make a servlet with event **/test**.
When I run execute url from browser I can not get cookie.
I only want check request is same client.

This is my code

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "-1");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    String userPath = request.getServletPath();

    if (userPath.equals("/test")) {
        String id = URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("id"), "UTF-8");
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if(cookies != null){
           System.out.println ("Name : " + cookies[0].getName());
        }
    }

}
```

But result **cookies** is null. Please help me this problem. I want check request is same client. Do you have idea help me about this problem.

Thank you so much!

Comment: There is no cookies in the request maybe.

Comment: In browser I call http://192.168.1.40/projectname/test?id=abc. If don't have cookie then how I can check same client? Please!

Comment: Try with `request.getRemoteAddr()`, but remember, all users behind a proxy will return same address.

Comment: So, do you know other way for check?

Comment: put a system.out.println(something...) after String userPath = request.getServletPath(); so you will now at least your method is executed, if not you know that it is a host, port etc... issue

Comment: Also what server and what port you are using? i.e. if its 8080 in windows write netstat -ano | findstr 8080 in linux netstat -tap | grep 8080 so you can see what port server is listening